# Symfony 5 : Unable to guess how to get a Doctrine instance from the request information for parameter "cennikDomacnosti"

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I just created new table in my database and "remap" my doctrine with:
`php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import "App\Entity" annotation --path=src/Entity` 
`php bin/console make:entity --regenerate App`

Now I´m trying to get data from that table like I did in another tables in my Project, but it doesn´t work. I use this:

```
     * @Route("/cenniky/{cennik}", name="cenniky")
     * @param $cennik
     * @param CennikDomacnosti $cennikDomacnosti
     * @return Response
     */
    public function cenniky($cennik,CennikDomacnosti $cennikDomacnosti): Response
    {
        $domacnosti=$cennikDomacnosti->findAll();

        return $this->render('base.html.twig',[
            "page" => "cenniky", "cennik" => $cennik,
            "title" => "PLUSIM | Priemyselné sťahovanie",
            "domacnosti" => $domacnosti,
        ]);
    }
```

For this Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * CennikDomacnosti
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="cennik_domacnosti")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class CennikDomacnosti
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cena", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $cena;

    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getCena(): ?string
    {
        return $this->cena;
    }

    public function setCena(string $cena): self
    {
        $this->cena = $cena;

        return $this;
    }


}
```

I tried to use @ParamConverter, but I don´t know how exactly to use it. I tried this:
`* @ParamConverter("cennik", options={"mapping": {"cennik"   : "cennik"}})`

Please, can anyone help me with this, because I don´t know how to fix it. Should I somehow "remap" doctrine entities properly?

Comment: I would try `public function cenniky(CennikDomacnosti $cennik): Response` the Entity called out with the same name as the placeholder should translate. Does that get you closer?

Comment: I need the $cennik from url for another function, I can´t rewrite it with that Entity... but when I tried it , there is still the same problem